# XML deserialisation of inner elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

Is it possible to deserialise an inner xml element to its equivilant class? I've got the following xml fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tileconfiguration xmlns="http://somenamespace/tile-configuration">
   <tile top_left_x="3" top_left_y="1" bottom_right_x="38" bottom_right_y="48">
     <child>
     </child>
   </tile>
</tileconfiguration>
```

and an equivalent class that represents the `<tile />`  element:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "tile")]
public class Tile : System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable
{
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The problem is, everytime I attempt to deserialize the instances of `<tile />` within the `<tile_configuration />` - the XML deserializer throws a **Error in document (2,2)**.

```
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serial = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Tile));
        System.IO.TextReader t = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\temp\\deserial.xml");
        Tile q = (Tile)serial.Deserialize(t);
```

If I create a class to represent `<tile_configuration />` and deserialise directly from that, it works fine and the debugger enters the `ReadXml` method on the `TileConfiguration` class from which I can then manage the parsing of the child `<tile />` (and decendent) elements - but this requires a re-read of the entire xml file each time.

In a nutshell; am I required to read and write the entire XML file - starting from the root xml element everytime I want to make use of serialisation/deserialisation or is there a way to allow me to ignore extranous outer elements and directly deserialise pertinent child xml elements to their code equivilents without the parser chucking errors?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore the outer elements and have full control and a fast implementation with low overhead I recommend to not use `XMLSerializer` but to use `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` respectively.

You could also make a combined approach by using a `XmlReader` to build your intermediate DOM and use an `XMLSerializer` to write the DOM to an output file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One idea is to load the xml and select the desired node using Xpath query. Then deserialize the xml represented by the result of query.

Comment: Thought it might be something like limiting the scope. Fantastic, thanks alot I'll give it a go.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've shown of your XML, it should not be necessary to implement IXmlSerializable. You can try this:

```
[XmlRoot("tileconfiguration")]
public class TileConfiguration
{
    [XmlElement("tile")]
    public List<Tile> Tiles { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("tile")]
public class Tile
{
    [XmlAttribute("top_left_x")]
    public int TopLeftX { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("top_left_y")]
    public int TopLeftY { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("bottom_right_x")]
    public int BottomRightX { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("bottom_right_y")]
    public int BottomRightY { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("child")]
    public List<Child> children { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("child")]
public class Child
{
}

XmlSerializer serializer = XmlSerializer(typeof(TileConfiguration));
TileConfiguration tileConfiguration = (TileConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

You could also use an XmlReader to fetch the element that you want:

```
List<Tile> tiles = new List<Tile>();
XmlSerializer serializer = XmlSerializer(typeof(Tile));

using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(xmlStream))
{
    while (!xr.EOF)
    {
        xr.MoveToContent();
        xr.ReadToDescendant("tile");

        if (xr.Name == "tile")
        {
            string tileXml = xr.ReadOuterXml();
            using (StringReader tileReader = new StringReader(tileXml))
            {
                Tile tile = (Tile)serializer.Deserialize(tileReader);
                tiles.Add(Tile);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            xr.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I implemented ISerializable because the example I have given is for illustration only. In the real-world there are a number of non-serializable objects that nest as children and require certain bespoke serialization operations that the 'automated' XMAttribute[] decoration cannot handle appropriately.